# Ruby + Titanium mobile

Tags: iphone, ruby, titanium

can Ruby be used to develop iphone app with Titanium mobile ? i read Titanium desktop can be developed with ruby, but is it possible for titanium mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot.
Ruby is available for desktop developement only. Like PHP, Python & Ruby.

For mobile development you can only use JavaScript in its provided API.